# Adding an mp3 file to a playlist on Banshee?

Tags: banshee, mp3

How do I add an mp3 file to my playlist on Banshee media player? In iTunes, I used to drag the .mp3 file into the window and it would automatically sync the music file into the playlist.  How can I do this with Banshee?

Answer (score 7):

**Simply, Add the mp3 file to Banshee**

[image]

**Then, right click on it, Add to Playlist.**

[image]